# How to switch to bit 32 Java in OS X Mavericks (10.9.1)

Tags: java, osx-mavericks, 32-bit

Title says it all, I need to run Java 32bit rather than the installed bit 64. How do I change that? I've used the

```
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
```

with no luck.

Comment: Some clarifications that may help you get better answers: Command line or other way of starting the JVM? Which Java/JRE? Apple's 1.6 or Oracle 1.7?

Comment: As far as the Oracle Java 7 goes there is no 32 bit version for OS X. Why do you need 32 bit?

Comment: @haraldK I'm using command line, and here are my Java specs: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

Comment: @greg-449 I'm trying to set up an xmpp server (Openfire) and it ONLY runs on Java 32bit.

Comment: The only reference I can see to OpenFire requiring 32 bit is about the preference pane

Comment: Java code is not compiled as 32bit/64bit so why is this a problem?

Comment: This isn't a "duplicate" because the last questioned wasn't answered you dick-magnets. Go mark the other question as a duplicate. This is why stackoverflow is so annoying. @Michael I'm not compiling Java code.

Comment: @Bootstrotter I agree that this question is not a duplicate because the other was never answered. What I meant is that Java code is not compiled to a specific bit size so if Openfire has problems then it's probably in supporting libraries.